# Why isn't my program interpreting the user's input correctly?

Tags: python, variables, input

My code:

```
    reask = input('So do you want me to solve a quadratic equation? Last chance or I will close and you have to start me again! Make sure you type \'yes\' or \'no\': ')
reask = reask.lower
if reask == 'yes':
    print ('Great!')
else:
    print ('See ya!')
    raise SystemExit
```

When the user inputs `'yes'`, the program interprets it as something else and ends up printing out `'See ya!'` then closing the program. It's supposed to print `'Great!'`. What's the issue?

Comment: You have a typo. `reask = reask.lower` should be `reask = reask.lower()`. You were setting `reask` to the function `lower`, rather than calling the function.

Comment: `reask.lower` returns the function object and not the result which you intended

Comment: Oh my god I didn't even care to look for that. Thanks!

Comment: How come parentheses are needed? Why isn't there anything in the parentheses?

Comment: Parentheses are needed to distinguish between the function itself, which is an object like any other, versus a _call_ to the function.  There is nothing in the parentheses because this particular function takes no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The line `reask = reask.lower` does not do what you think it does. It binds the name `reask` to the method `str.lower` bound to the user input string.

To call this method and assign the result instead of the method itself, do `reask = reask.lower()`.

Alternatively, you can keep the assignment as-is and change the conditional to `if reask() == 'yes':`. That would call the method just the same.